# The operation 'response' cannot be used inside a for each

Tags: office365, power-automate

I am trying to add `Response` action in Power Automate. But there is an error `The operation 'response' cannot be used inside a for each.`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to place the Response action within an apply to each loop action. Can you place that action outside of that loop action?

Below is an example which demonstrates the same issue and also an example that the response action is allowed outside the apply to each.

[image]